# UITableViewCell wrap text in UINavigationController app

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am having a tableview with different heights for each cell based on the size of the text.
I calculate the rowsize in the delegate method `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`, and assign to the text in the datasource method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
I am able to realize the appropriate height based on the text, but am not able to make the text wrap around; instead it just disappears off the screen. I am using a navigation-based app to generate the tableview in the child view controller using a nib. I played around with some of the options for tableview, but I can't make the text wrap. I would like to see the next wrap as if it were a textview, but I want the entire content displayed in the cell, without scroll bars in the table cell itself. Is this possible?

Here is the updated code, the height is adjusting itself correctly, but the cell is not word wrapping...

-

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *string = [self.quizDictionary objectForKey:[_temp objectAtIndex:testKV]];

    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) 
                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return stringSize.height+25;
} 


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    int row = indexPath.row;
    if (row > 6) {
        return nil;
    }
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] 
                autorelease];
        } 
    // configure the cell...
    NSString *string = [self getQuestionPart];

    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    UITextView *textV=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 290, stringSize.height+10)];
    textV.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    textV.text=string;
    textV.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
 // textV.editable=NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textV];
    [textV release];
    testKV++; 
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

to get your text to wrap within the cell. This in combination with a careful implementation of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible!!!

Looking at this,you need to be somewhat tricky. You need to calculate the height of the textView dynamically and based on the Height of the TextView,you need to return the Height for the cell..

This is the code by which you can calculate the size of string....

**First get the size of String & set the height of the cell based on string**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {  

    NSDictionary *d=(NSDictionary *)[self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *label =  [d valueForKey:@"Description"];
    CGSize stringSize = [label sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) 
                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return stringSize.height+25;

} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //}

    NSDictionary *d=(NSDictionary *)[self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *string = [d valueForKey:@"Description"];
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    UITextView *textV=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 290, stringSize.height+10)];
    textV.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    textV.text=string;
    textV.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    textV.editable=NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:twitLbl];
    [twitLbl release];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Ajay, I added the above code, but it is not wrapping. I edited my original question to add cellForRowAtIndexPath and -heightForRowAtIndexPath (I had to change twitlbl to textV, correct?) and had to comment out textV.editable=NO

Comment: because I got NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel setEditable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b7cd90